# Out of memory on srv:listen

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I searched all the web but didn't find an answer.
I want to set up a wifi AP and a webserver on the NodeMCU.

I use the following code:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)
wifi.ap.config({ ssid = "test", pwd = "12345678" })
print("Server IP Address:", wifi.ap.getip())

srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(sck, request)
        print("received: " .. request)
        sck:send("echo: " .. request)
    end)
end)
```

This is what I get after uploading:

```
> dofile("init.lua");
Server IP Address:  192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0   192.168.1.1
init.lua:6: out of memory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'listen'
    init.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

The firmware I use:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: c708828bbe853764b9de58fb8113a70f5a24002d
    SSL: false
    modules: file,gpio,net,node,tmr,uart,wifi
 build created on 2018-11-05 22:20
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(6ab97e9)
```

Any clues on how to get it working?

Comment: Why are you writing `s:send` instead of `sck:send` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks for pointing that out, I edited the post, but I still get same error.

Comment: 1) I cannot reproduce this here with the same firmware. 2) "Server IP Address:  192.168.1.1" looks really odd to me. I would expect 192.168.1.1 to be your "real" AP's IP address. In my environment the ESP get the default IP address 192.168.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've managed to find out the reason.

**TLDR**: press reset button on the board before running your lua script.

The problem was not about memory shortage. It was error on allocating a network port. If you have the same problem, you can see, that if you change port number in your script, it starts correctly, but on the next run of the same script it fails with "out of memory error". If so, just press reset button on the board and try to run it again.